# Get exception when using injection with a simple HelloEJB project

Tags: ejb, code-injection

I am now learning EJB and got a problem when testing the Injection functionality. Here is my code (I create an EJB project in Eclipse).

I run the EJB with embedded Glassfish, and run the test(main) independently, but always get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.MainUsingInjection.runTest(MainUsingInjection.java:11)
    at com.example.MainUsingInjection.main(MainUsingInjection.java:20)
```

I hope anyone can help me with this. Thank you very much.

**HelloSessionBean.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HelloSessionBean implements HelloSessionBeanRemote {

    public HelloSessionBean() {   }

    public void helloMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!\n");
    }

}
```

**HelloSessionBeanRemote.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloSessionBeanRemote {
    public void helloMethod();
}
```

**MainUsingJnjection.java**

```
package com.example;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class MainUsingInjection {

    @EJB(name="HelloSessionBean")
    public static HelloSessionBeanRemote bean;

    public void runTest() throws Exception {
        bean.helloMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainUsingInjection cli = new MainUsingInjection();
        try {
            cli.runTest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace suggests that you've directly launched the main method. In order to use injection in the main class, you must use the [application client container](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/client/thinclient.html#wp1079680).